# Thermistor sensor with xbee

Tags: sensors, arduino-uno, xbee

Can I connect thermistor sensor to the analogue pin of XBee to read the human body temperature?

I want to get human body temperature through XBee.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can read temperature from a temperature sensor that is integrated with xbee but you also need another xbee that is connected to another microcontroller to read these values that are sent.